# ExpandableListAdapter - Cannot instantiate the type ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse, expandablelistadapter

I was working on a `ExpandableListView` with this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/).

On `MainActivity.java` section, there is an error at

`listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);` line.

I changed my `ExpandableListAdapter.java` class name, but MainActivity still have the error.

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get the listView
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.qlist_main);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: post the code which is causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandableListAdapter` is an interface, so you can't instantiate it. Create your own adapter implementing it, instead.